# Embedding a torus

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

This question is motivated by the previous one ([Can a flat space be closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895854/can-a-flat-space-be-closed)), although not directly related. When we think of a torus shape in real life, we probably first think of a donut. However, in the linked question, a 3-torus is described more like "an infinite mirrors cube" than anything like a curved donut. This actually makes a lot of sense, but also indicates that a donut may not be the best representation of a 2-torus.

If my thinking is correct, a 1-torus embedded in a 2D Euclidean space is just a circle (or any closed loop perhaps, but let's use a circle for simplicity). Now, if I try to construct a 2-torus, I first think of a flat sheet of paper rolled into a tube. This closes my 2-torus along one dimension. To close it along the other dimension, I must connect the ends of the tube, but without stretching the paper. Stretching would represent a space curvature, but the 2-torus is flat.

I know there are different definitions of curvature and that a donut may be mapped to a 2-torus by, I assume, defining the angular distance as independent of the radius. However, this question is about a straightforward embedding with no mapping (apologies if my terminology is off).

So it appears that I cannot do this in 3 dimensions and that I would need an extra dimension. Is this correct that a 2-torus can be embedded in at minimum in a 4D Euclidean space? Also, what number of dimensions is required to embed a 3-torus $\mathbb T^3$in a flat Euclidean space?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for an *isometric* embedding; one that respects distances (and hence angles and curvature). Is that right? If so, you're right that the flat $2$-torus can't be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ but can be in $\mathbb{R}^4$. For the general case see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, this sounds right. Thanks for your insight! How about the flat 3-torus? Thanks for the theorem reference as well!

Comment: I do want to point out that if you relax the regularity (smoothness) of the embedding, then you can in fact find an isometric embedding of the flat torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For example: http://hevea-project.fr/ENPageToreDossierDePresse.html
The key thing to note is that this map is only $C^1$, and so curvature isn't even defined

Comment: @yousufsoliman Great link, thanks! I did think that I could perhaps crumble the tube to make its ends meet and that crumbling is not a curvature. I felt though that it would not work simply and now I see that it would require fractals.

Comment: @safesphere Exactly. These $C^1$ embedding can be extremely unintuitive... in fact, there are infinitely many such embeddings. For example, any closed oriented surface can be isometrically embedded in an $\varepsilon$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$! This is noted in the Wikipedia article Qiachu Yuan linked. The link I provided above provides one such construction, which I think is quite intuitive