# Which surfaces can be isometrically embedded in a flat 3-space?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

In 1971 [Jacobowitz proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24890382) that it is always possible to locally isometrically embed a surface in $\mathbb R^4$ (thanks to @doetoe for the reference). Not all surfaces can be locally isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, but some can. What is the condition a surface must obey to be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$?

For example. a segment of a 2-sphere can be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. However, a segment of 2-torus cannot (see the comment of @QiaochuYuan here: [Embedding a torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929493/embedding-a-torus)). My intuition is that a 2-torus has an extrinsic curvature in 2 orthogonal non-intersecting planes, which are possible in $\mathbb R^4$, but not in $\mathbb R^3$.

What condition or limitation must be put on a surface (e.g on its metric or curvature or anything else) to allow an isometric embedding this surface in $\mathbb R^3$?

**EDIT** - based on the comment of @MoisheCohen (thanks!):

1. Please disregard my example of embedding of a 2-torus in $\mathbb R^3$ at the moment.
2. The degree of smoothness is that the surface is twice differentiable in every point.
3. Both necessary and sufficient conditions. If I have  a differential equation for surfaces, then, out of all possible solutions, I need only and all of those, which can be isometrically embedded.
4. The embedding is local (e.g as pictured below).

[image]

Comment: Of course, the flat torus can be locally isometrically embedded in $E^3$: Just use a small open subset of a plane in 3-space. I think  QY was talking about a global isometric embedding. For your question, you should specify the degree of smoothness and clarify if you want necessary or sufficient conditions for the existence of a (local or global?) isometric embedding.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks for your comment! I have updated the question and would greatly appreciate if you post an answer or share any insight.

Comment: The local question is answered by the Burstin-Cartan-Janet Theorem. Given a *real analytic* Riemannian metric, for every point there is a neighborhood and an isometric embedding in $\Bbb R^3$ of that neighborhood. See Spivak, *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, vol. 5, pp. 149 ff, or Bryant, Chern, Gardner, Goldschmidt, Griffiths, *Exterior Differential Systems*, pp. 98 ff.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have posted an updated question that hopefully is phrased in a more logical way reflecting the problem at hand: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131651/what-2-surface-can-be-enclosed-in-3-volume