# What 2-surface can be enclosed in 3-volume?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Consider a 2-surface $S$ defined in $\Bbb{R}^n$ ($n>3$) either directly as $F(x_1, x_2,... \, x_n) = 0$ or parametrically as $(x_1,... \, x_n) = (F_1(u, v),... F_n(u, v))$. Assume $S$ is simple connected, non singular, not self intersecting, and at least twice differentiable.

Consider $V$ is an $\Bbb{R}^3$ sub-manifold with coordinates linear in the $\Bbb{R}^n$. In other words, V is defined by rotation, translation, and dropping of $n-3$ coordinates. The objective for $V$ Is to enclose $S$. This may or may not be possible depending on $S$.

For example, a 2-sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2-R^2=0$ can be enclosed in $\Bbb{R}^3=(x, y, z)$ globally or locally, but a flat 2-torus $(x, y, z, w) = (R \cos(u), R \sin(u), P \cos(v), P \sin(v))$ cannot be enclosed in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (as defined above) either globally or even locally in a neighborhood of any point on the surface.

[image]

What necessary and sufficient conditions must $S$ satisfy for the existence of $V$ enclosing $S$ globally and/or locally?

Comment: Are you asking which surfaces are contained in a 3 dimensional affine subspace?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Upon a quick lookup, apparently yes, I am asking about a 3D affine subspace (or linear manifold) equipped with an Euclidean metric.

Comment: A very-physics perspective: In GR, to find better coordinates that cover the
entire spacetime (of Minkowskian flavour), we have to embed the spacetime
as a hyperplane into a higher dimensional Minkowski space in order to find
coordinates that cover the hyperplane completely, and hence, cover the entire
original curved spacetime. This dictates choosing a special coordinate transform (here, the Kruskal-Szekeres coodinates) and thinking of the Schwarzschild metric as an induced metric on a 4-dimensional hyperplane embedded in a flat 6-dimensional spacetime.

Comment: Often wave coordinates are employed since they act as an effective tool for the PDE analysis of spacetimes. Solving for the Schwarzschild metric in n-dimensions, where n>3, and exploiting spherical symmetry we obtain solutions imposing the harmonicity conditions on the metric. @safesphere, I can write that if a very-physics approach is fine with you.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji Thanks for your comments. (1) Why do we need the K-S coordinates to embed the Sch. solution? I realize the physical coordinates become singular at the EH, but so what? The ambient space is infinite too, why do we care? Does the K-S transform allow for fewer ambient dimensions or simpler formulas or is the solution non embeddable at all in the physical (Sch.) coordinates? (2) I understand your perspective, but my question is slightly different. Instead of finding the number of the ambient dimensions needed for a given hypersurface, I want to know how to limit the hypersurface...

Comment: @NaveenBalaji ... to the given number of the ambient dimensions. For example, you say the Sch. solution needs 6 ambient dimensions. Then my question is how I can modify this solution to be embed in a fewer number of dimensions, say, 5. I realize the result is no longer the Sch. solution, as the formulas have changed, and also that it is no longer a solution of the gravitational equations at all, and finally that this reduction is not unique. All this is fine with me. Again, I am not embedding the existing solutions. I am asking, what can be embedded in a given number of the ambient dimensions.

Comment: @safesphere As you have mentioned the Sch. sol is no longer itself in 5 dimensions . In fact it was Kasner who showed that we can't construct 4-D manifolds, other than the trivial Euclidean type, in a flat space of 5 dimensions which obey Einstein's equations. It is possible to embed the Schwarzschild
spacetime and both of its extensions in a larger spacetime which contains
an additional copy of the Schwarzschild spacetime, i.e. there exists a larger manifold. The manifold description of the Fronsdal embedding is closely related to the use of K-S coordinates. 
coordinates

Comment: @safesphere as for the question of what can be embedded in a given number of dimensions, we first apply the isotropic coodinates to the Sch. metric in n+1 dimensions and consider a general spherically static metric in n+1 dimensions which we subject to the harmonicity conditions. Upon comparison to the standard form we obtain asymptotic expansions of the isotropic coordinate in different dimensions. Thus, the asymptotic expansions tell you what form of the metric can be embedded in a given number of dimensions.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji This does sound close to what I am asking. Would you be able to write an answer by following this procedure with formulas on an example of reducing the Sch. solution from 6 to 5 dimensions? (After which it is of course no longer the same and may not be a valid solution, but it is fine.) If you can, then perhaps Physics SE would be a better place for GR where I also have essentially the same question posted regarding GR and I'd be happy to accept this answer there.Thank you so much! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460058/metric-of-a-cross-section-in-general-relativity